# How can I speed this Eloquent Query up?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

The following query is retrieving a large data set (~25k rows). It is running very slowly, and I would like to know how to speed it up:

```
$jobs = Job::whereArchived(true)->get();

    foreach ($jobs AS $job)
    {
        $rows[] = [
            "<a href='/admin/projects/jobs/$job->id'>{$job->name}</a>",
            $job->start_date ? $job->start_date : "Not Specified",
            $job->end_date ? $job->end_date : "Not Specified", 
            $job->agent ? $job->agent->name : "Unassigned",
            $job->status ? $job->status : "Not Specified"

        ];
    }
echo Html::table()
    ->head($headers)
    ->body($rows)
    ->datatable();
```

This particular query / result is taking around 60 seconds to complete at least. How can I speed this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to eagerly load related **agent** model, otherwise for every **Job** record additional query is run when you try to access **$job->agent**.

Replace

```
$jobs = Job::whereArchived(true)->get();
```

with

```
$jobs = Job::with('agent')->whereArchived(true)->get();
```

and you should see significant improvement in the query performance.

If the logic still takes too long for your needs, you might want to skip Eloquent layer completely, as another reason why your query might take a lot of time to execute is that you're fetching the data using the Eloquent model - because of that for every row that is fetched from the database an object of class **Job** needs to be created.

Processing large amount of data is more efficient if you fetch data as an array and skip the logic that creates objects out of it. You can do that by fetching the data using the **DB facade**:

```
$jobs = DB::table('jobs')->where('archived', '=', true)->join('agents', 'jobs.agent_id', '=', 'agents.id')->get();
```

That should give a significant performance boost as well.

Yet another reason is that you're fetching all available columns from the database instead of only the ones that you need, which increases the memory usage and the time needed to transfer the data from the database to your application. You can fix that by specifying the list of columns that you're gonna need so that only those columns are loaded:

```
$jobs = Job::with('agent')->whereArchived(true)
  ->get(['name', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'status']);

$jobs = DB::table('jobs')->where('archived', '=', true)
  ->join('agents', 'jobs.agent_id', '=', 'agents.id')
  ->get(['name', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'status']);
```

Finally, think whether you really need to display all records at once. Usually that's not required and paginated results can be displayed instead. You can find more information about pagination together with some examples in the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/pagination

Answer (score 1):

You can eager load related models using with() function as specified in other answer but fetching 25k results in a single query is not a good approach. Pagination is the good candidate for this situation and you can use ajax to fetch rest of the pages.
If pagination is not an option for you then try to index the column 'archived' and use eager loading to fetch results. It will significantly increase the query performance.